# Https and Basic Authentication with Apache HttpClient

Tags: java, ssl, https, woocommerce, httpclient

i'm trying implement Java client for WooCommerce API.
I am able to do following curl query:

```
curl https://myserver/wc-api/v3/products -k -u  ck_mykey:cs_mysecret
```

and get relevant answer. **-k** stands for insecure connection.

I'm using **Apache HttpClient 4.x** for http connections. 
Googling gave me some examples with **HttpClient 3.x**. In HttpClient 4.x
are most of what implemented in 3.x deprecated. So, could anyone share some Java + HttpClient implementaion for
**https** client with **Basic Authentication**.

**EDIT:**

Ok, let me rephrase my problem. I got fluently work such code which
does Basic Auth for GET request via BasicAuthCache:

```
public static void getWithBasicAuth(String host, String url, String username, String password)
        throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {

    HttpHost target = new HttpHost(host, 80, "http");
    CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    credsProvider.setCredentials(new AuthScope(target.getHostName(), target.getPort()),
            new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password));
    CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom().setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider).build();
    try {
        AuthCache authCache = new BasicAuthCache();
        BasicScheme basicAuth = new BasicScheme();
        authCache.put(target, basicAuth);
        HttpClientContext localContext = HttpClientContext.create();
        localContext.setAuthCache(authCache);

        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);

        System.out.println("Executing request " + httpget.getRequestLine() + " to target " + target);
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(target, httpget, localContext);
            try {
                System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
                System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
                System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
            } finally {
                response.close();
            }
        }
    } finally {
        httpclient.close();
    }
}
```

But how i should wrap such method into **ssl**?

Comment: Please consider performing some variations to your search. Here you go: https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/quickstart.html

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer what works at least for me. 
Here made only changes to add SSL support to initial GET request with Basic Authentication:

```
public static void getWithBasicAuthSSL(String host, String url, String username, String password)
        throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException, KeyManagementException {

    SSLContextBuilder builder = new SSLContextBuilder();
    builder.loadTrustMaterial(null, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy());
    SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(
            builder.build());



    HttpHost target = new HttpHost(host, 443, "https");
    CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    credsProvider.setCredentials(new AuthScope(target.getHostName(), target.getPort()),
            new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password));

    CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom().setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider).setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf).build();

    try {
        AuthCache authCache = new BasicAuthCache();
        BasicScheme basicAuth = new BasicScheme();
        authCache.put(target, basicAuth);
        HttpClientContext localContext = HttpClientContext.create();
        localContext.setAuthCache(authCache);

        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);

        System.out.println("Executing request " + httpget.getRequestLine() + " to target " + target);
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(target, httpget, localContext);
            try {
                System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
                System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
                System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
            } finally {
                response.close();
            }
        }
    } finally {
        httpclient.close();
    }
}
```